# How to set the proxy_pass to get the desired address?

Tags: nginx, reverse-proxy, redirect, nginx-location, nginx-reverse-proxy

I have been struggling with setting up Nginx for our use case.

When I set up Nginx with the following config:

```
location /dep-core {
    proxy_pass http://node-server:7070/;
}
```

and call the server with following endpoint:
 `<END-POINT>/dep-core/api/login`

the call is redirected to 
`<ADDRESS-AFTER-RESOLUTION>//api/login` 
with two leading //s.

and when I remove the trailing / in proxy_pass after 7070:

```
location /dep-core {
    proxy_pass http://node-server:7070;
}
```

the call is redirected to 
`<ADDRESS-AFTER-RESOLUTION>/dep-core/api/login` 
with leading /dep-core appended.

I want my call to redirect my call to:
`<ADDRESS-AFTER-RESOLUTION>/api/login`
What would be the standard way to achieve this??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For correct translation from `/dep-core/foo` to `/foo`, the `location` directive requires a trailing `/`.

For example:

```
location /dep-core/ { 
    proxy_pass http://node-server:7070/; 
}
```

See [this document](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_proxy_module.html#proxy_pass) for details.

---

To translate `/dep-core` to `/`, you can use a `rewrite...break` with a clever regular expression in the second block of your question. But a simple solution is to add an exact match `location` for that single edge case.

For example:

```
location = /dep-core {
    rewrite ^ $uri/ last;
}
location /dep-core/ { 
    proxy_pass http://node-server:7070/; 
}
```

Comment: Thank you.
This works as expected with only one case not covering.
With this config, calls to `/dep-core` are not resolved and only `/dep-core/` calls get resolved. Anything to remove this undesired behavior?